# Pandas: use of aggregate with a MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate, finance

I have a question about the correct use of `agg` in `pandas`. The specific problem I am working on is in the field of finance and, more specifically, is to calculate a liquidity measure from the full limit order book.

My data contain the ask side of the order book (which represents how many shares people want to sell at a particular moment and at which price) and I want to calculate the hypothetical price for buying 50 shares at a specific moment in time. Assume for example that the order book for stock X at 9am looks like this:

```
example_data=pd.DataFrame({'price':[100.023,100.031,100.039,100.109,100.219 ],'avail_shares':      [40,1,20,23,15],'midpoint':[99.996 ,99.996 ,99.996 ,99.996,99.996 ]})
```

where price is the price at which shares are sold, avail_shares the number of shares available at each price and midpoint the average of the best ask and bid price in the order book. To get a liquidity measure that takes into account that a large order can hit multiple price levels at once (i.e. ‘walk the book’)  I define the following cost-to-trade (ctt) function:

```
def ctt_ask(dfrm,level=50):
    dfrm['cumshares']=dfrm['avail_shares'].cumsum()
    dfrm['indicator']=0
    dfrm['indicator'].ix[dfrm.cumshares<level,]=dfrm.cumshares
    dfrm['indicator'].ix[(dfrm.cumshares>level) & (dfrm.cumshares.shift(1)<level),]=(level-  dfrm.cumshares.shift(1))
   liquidity_measure=((dfrm.price-dfrm.midpoint)*dfrm.indicator).sum()
    return liquidity_measure
```

This works just fine (i.e. `ctt_ask(example_data)` yields 2.90) for the above example but my real dataset has several stocks and many date times (it has a `MultiIndex`). When I use `groupby` and `agg` to apply this function to every stock-date time combination (    `full_book_ask.groupby(level=[0,1]).agg(ctt_ask)`) I get an error: `KeyError: 'avail_shares'`. This is strange because I do have a column named avail_shares in my actual dataset.  I have also tried the same with the `apply` functionality but this raises the error message `Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`
. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong here. Any input would be much appreciated!

Comment: Getting a `KeyError` when you try to access a column that you don't have seems pretty intuitive to me. What do you expect to happen?

Comment: The issue is that the first argument that is automatically passed to agg is a series (for each column in the data frame which is to be aggregated) and not the dataframe itself. This means that you cannot reference columns other than the one to be aggregated. This is why is works just fine when you are not doing this with groupby. You can try using `transform` as the object passed to transform is the entire dataframe within the group.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. @Paul H, as I state in the description there is a column called avail_shares in my dataset so this can't be the issue. @Woody Pride, you are correct, I understand now why I can't use `agg`. However, both `apply` and `transform` give me an error as well: `Exception: cannot handle a non-unique multi-index!`. So there must be something else going on. I guess there is a problem with the use of `ix` but I don't know why or what I should do to solve it.